# Can I use "to bring it"?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused that whether I can use "to bring it" or not in grammar.

because as I know, we can't use "to with verb" not "to verb+ing". for example,

> "Should I have to go back to my room to bring it?"

If I wrong. please correct to me.

## update

I came across some relative sentence as the below when I googling.

> "bring the water to the boil "

I understand that sentence like someone ask to get some water to boil the water.

Is this right I understood?

what if I want to express that the what am I supposed to do?

Comment: We usually use ***bring*** when we're speaking *from the **final** location of the thing to be moved*, so your example isn't very idiomatic. Most people would either ask ***Should** I go back to my room to **fetch** it?* or ***Do** I have to go back to my room to **fetch** it?* (as the introduction to a *question* the combination ***should I have to*** doesn't work in this context either).

Comment: Bring  is fine if both speakers are in the same location. Shall I bring you some tea? [If I am in the same place as you.]. "Should I have to" does work if the person is commenting in context or whining about having to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to bring it** is fine but in that particular question **to bring it** is not used properly, not unless the question is modified in some way, such as **to bring it *here***. You would want to say **get** or **fetch** instead of **bring**.

You can **bring** only that which you see yourself as *not unable* to bring.

> Shall I bring this camera to the beach with us?
>
> Can I bring a date to a wedding?

Since you don't have it and need to go get it before you would be able to bring it, you wouldn't say **bring** there.

This would be idiomatic:

> Should I go back to my room and get it so I can bring it?
>
> Should I go back to my room and bring it here?

Answer (score 0):

Should I have to go back to my room to bring it **here**?

Bring (despite what some people may say) is to the place where the speaker is.

(Please note, in AmE people tend to say/use bring for take. Take is actually away from the speaker: Please take these clothes to your room (You are not in your room). In AmE, people tend to say: Please bring these clothes to your room. Just pointing this out.)

So, you can ask someone who is with you the question by adding the word "here" to mean the place where you as speaker and your interlocutor are located.

Comment: Bearing in mind Lambie's AmE comment, what about: **I'm in London at present but I can meet you in Paris at the weekend. Please bring my watch with you when you come?**

Comment: That is not the mistake AmE speakers make: they make the following mistake. **You and I are in the same place**, and I say to you: **Can you bring me to the swimming pool this afternoon?** Obviously, for the watch, it's bring to where the speaker will be.

Comment: No, in  your example, bring is actually correct, with you is wrong: Please bring my watch to me when you come [we will both be in Paris at that point]. Because: "Please take my watch with you" would mean or imply I will not be there. As this does: Please take my tennis racket with you [on your trip] if you can't find your own.